# How to make all db records start with a specific value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL DB that contains a real data for clients,
what I want to do is to make a SQL update query to update the phone column in clients table and make all its records start with '966'

can any one help me make this query?

Answer (score 3):

Presumably, it would be something like this:

```
update t
    set phone = concat('966', phone)
    where phone not like '966%';
```

Answer (score 1):

update t
    set phone = concat('966', phone)
    where substr(phone,1,3)!=966